# Shell script code browser

Tags: shell

Is there a shell script code browser like ctags for c?

Probably not I think, a recommended editor for shell script code browsing would also do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use or like `emacs`, you could try the [Emacs Code Browser](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) (ECB).

Answer (score 0):

[Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) (also called `exctags`, which is installed as `ctags` on many Linux distributions) also parses shell scripts and creates tags for shell functions. Just use `ctags --language-force=sh script`.